# Accessing a global variable inside a promise-callback (in Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

i am working on an App which should check the online status before data is sent to an API. Based on the status it should also route to a different location. Prior to the XHR some data is used from the local storage which works out. I can pass and log the status within a callback, but this.router.navigate() and this.storage.remove() then won't work.

I tried ngZone as well to do the routing but it failed (undefined). Next thing I'd try is a .bind() but my head is kinda blocked atm.

I would appreciate a hint what i could try (next).

Here's the **component** which calls the service:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { SaveData } from '../saveData.service'
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-save',
    templateUrl: './save.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./save.page.scss'],
})

export class SavePage {
    constructor(private saveData: SaveData) { }

    async ionViewDidEnter() { 
        this.saveData.do('url/to/api.php', this.saveData.mycallback);
    }
}
```

And the **service**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})

export class SaveData {
    constructor(
        private getData: GetData,
        private router: Router,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {}
  
    async mycallback(connection) {
        console.log("from callback:", connection)
      
        if (connection === 'ok') {
            await this.storage.remove('Orders')
            this.router.navigate(['somewhere']);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['somewhere_else']);
        }
      
        do = async (fetchURL, callback) {
            var requestURL = (await this.storage.get('server')) + fetchURL;
            console.log('REQ-URL:', requestURL);
            var requestparam =
                'auth=' + (await this.storage.get('token')) +
                '&json=' + JSON.stringify(await this.storage.get('Orders'));
                
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', requestURL, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    var status = xhr.status;
                    if (status >= 200 && status < 400) {
                        console.log('connection OK');
                        let connection = "ok";
                        callback(connection);
                    } else {
                        console.log('connection BAD');
                        let connection = "bad";
                        callback(connection);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(requestparam);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are u putting async and await everywhere? On ionic view did enter no need to async,on my call back no need to async, on storage no need to await, u could just do every thing normally, the only place u could use async and await in this example is in the storage service itself, on the remove function in storage, if u are using native storage only u can use async and await...now what is hapoening is the await is being called to await something, but nothing to be awaited and thus nothing to be triggered, thus remove from storage and router are not working since they are unreachable...

Comment: Hello @MostafaHarb , some of the async/await were used because ionic-storage wouldn't return the values (or so i thought). I tried another way now and used fetch(). the script works now .. when status is 200 it removes the items froms storage and routes somewhere. if there is no connection or a network problem it will not clean the storage and route somewhere else. ( will add the new approach soon )

Answer (score 0):

OK here is a new and working approach with `fetch()` and a little help of Postman. It will throw an error whenever there is a problem with the network or give back a status response if the fetch reached the other side. And here I can still use my needed global variables.

```js
async do() {  
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
let urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("auth", await this.storage.get('token'));
urlencoded.append("json",  JSON.stringify(await this.storage.get('Orders')));
    
let requestOptions = {

   method: 'POST',
   headers: myHeaders,
   body: urlencoded,

}
    
fetch("url/to/fetch", requestOptions)

    .then(async response => {
          
       console.log("STATUS",response.status);
       if (response.status == 200) {
          await this.storage.remove('Orders');
          this.router.navigate(['somewhere'])
       }})

     .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error);
        this.router.navigate(['somwhere-else'])
      })
```